# Swift : Firebase query never goes in call

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im trying to access to my firebase db with Swift

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseAuth
import Firebase

struct FirebaseManager {

    private let reference = Database.database().reference()

    func fetch (_ child: String, completion: @escaping (DataSnapshot) -> Void) {
        print("before reference")
        reference
            .child(child)
            .observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapdata) in
            print("inside reference")
            guard let response = snapdata.value else { return print("error snapdata") }
            print(response)
            completion(snapdata)
        }
        print("after reference")
    }
}
```

To check if code is running correctly, I put some prints and this is what I see in Xcode console:

```
before reference
after reference
```

There's neither "inside reference" nor response value nor "error snapdata"

So I've deduced it never goes inside it ! And I checked: my firebase db is not empty and corresponds to child parameter string.

I don't understand where is the problem.

Same problem here : [iOS Swift - Firebase query never gets called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37958065/ios-swift-firebase-query-never-gets-called)

**EDIT:** I also tried this:

```
.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    print("observe single event")
            if snapshot.exists() {
                if let value = snapshot.value as? String {
                    print("inside if let", value)
                }
            } else {
                print("else")
                // username doesn't exist
            }

        }, withCancel:{ error in
         print("cancel", error)
        })
```

And the ouput in console is the same. Nothing appears

And this is a screenshot in rules:

[image]

Comment: You might want to use [`observeSingleEvent(of:with:withCancel:)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DatabaseQuery#/c:objc(cs)FIRDatabaseQuery(im)observeSingleEventOfType:withBlock:withCancelBlock:) instead, to see if the query gets cancelled by the database. If it does, the user does not have permission to read the data, and you should read the documentation on [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [`observeSingleEvent(of:with:withCancel:)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DatabaseQuery#/c:objc(cs)FIRDatabaseQuery(im)observeSingleEventOfType:withBlock:withCancelBlock:) instead, to see if the query gets cancelled by the database. If it does, the user does not have permission to read the data, and you should read the documentation on [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security).

Comment: I tried ObserveSingleEvent already, and same problem.
I cheked the permission to read data, and all rules are true:
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}